# How to extend from const constructor

Tags: dart, constants

`class` and `const` gives a nice possibility to define structured constants. Now I try to extend from one, works ok. Try to use a constant from the inherited class, it works, still I only manage to get through with `final` instead of `const`. No big deal in my project, but is it possible to have it `const`?

```
class A {
  final String name;
  final int value;
  const A(final String this.name, final this.value);
  static const A ONE = const A('One', 1);
}

class B extends A {

  const B(final String name, final int val) : super(name, val);

  static const B B_ONE = const B('One', 1);//Ok
  static const A A_ONE = A.ONE;//Ok
  static final B BA_ONE = new B(A.ONE.name, A.ONE.value);//Ok
  static const B BA_ONE_CONST = const B(A.ONE);//No B constructor!?!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `B` class indeed does not have a constructor that takes a single `A` instance. You haven't declared one, and you can't do it directly without a little workaround.

The problem is that `B` *extends* `A`, it doesn't just contain an `A` instance. So, if you want to start with an `A` instance (like `A.ONE`) and create a `B` instance from it, where `B` extends `A` and has its own `name` and `value` fields, you'll have to extract the `name` and `value` from the `A` to create the new object ... and you can't do property extraction in a const expression. So, that's a no-go.

What you can do is to have a different implementation of `B` that gets its values directly from an `A` instance, and then create a constant from that:

```dart
class B extends A {
  const B(String name, int value) : super(name, value);
  const factory B.fromA(A instance) = _SecretB;
  ...
  static const B BA_ONE_CONST = const B.fromA(A.ONE);
}
class _SecretB implements B {
  final A _instance;
  const _SecretB(this._instance);
  String get name => _instance.name;
  int get value => _instance.value;
}
```

If you are the only one using the `B.fromA` constructor, you could just remove it and call the `_SecretB` constructor directly. If you want to expose it to other clients of your class, you can make it a `const factory` constructor like here.

Comment: Great, thanks. For my project not critical with `const` instead of `final`. Also tried that with the property extraction, but don't works for `const` construction. `A.ONE.name` isn't interpreted as a `const`.